# A way to charge and use a battery without having to manually swap connections?

Tags: batteries

I am trying to make a automated system for a home project. The system will use power from a solar panel, storing the energy in a battery and then the battery powers a 12V motor and the power going from the battery to the motor is being controlled by an Arduino. The motor isn't always in use, only a few times throughout the day for a few seconds. As the title says, I'm looking for a way to be able to charge the battery and then use the batteries power when needed without having to manually swap from charging to use. I was thinking of using relays on either side of the battery to stop the battery from drawing power when the motor isn't is use but after some reading I get the sense that this isn't a wise idea. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What type of battery?

Comment: @bobflux Was thinking using a LiPo but im open to other types

Comment: Depending on your solar array and battery type, you may well be able to buy a charge controller that does what you want without having to swap or disconnect anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recharging a Lipo battery while using it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539946/recharging-a-lipo-battery-while-using-it) There are other ICs that can do this, try googling "load sharing Li-po charger" or similar.

Comment: There usually is no reason to disconnect a charger from the battery when you are drawing power from the battery. Battery chargers are current-limited. They will not be harmed by supplying power to the load.

Comment: @SimonB Thank you, for now I will get the charge controller but eventually I will look at making my own for the purpose of learning

Comment: @ocrdu For now that circuitry is a bit beyond my experience but eventually I will look into it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SolomonSlow I will use a charge controller because like what you said below, I would need to make sure I don't discharge the battery too deeply. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how, using a charge controller.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram assumes a three-port charge controller with separate connections for the solar panel, the battery, and the load. But, cheaper solar chargers lack the load port. In that case, you can simply connect the load directly to the battery. The only advantage to having a separate load port is that the controller will switch it off if the battery voltage drops below some safe threshold. (maybe, 10.5 or 11 Volts). If you connect your load directly to the battery, then it becomes your own responsibility to make sure you don't discharge the battery too deeply.

Comment: @Solomon Slow - Thank you very much for the feedback.